# windows. can i make my own terminal/console and how do i get that terminal/console to display std::cout

Tags: c++, windows

id like to build a program, that can run another program or multiple programs and then when those program "prints" / uses std::cout, it shows up in the console/terminal that i have built.
i also wish for those programs to be able to read input from the terminal i have built and that it can run a program written in any language and work just the same with that language's version of std::cout.

im aware of how to get the gui stuff done and how to get a program to run other programs. but im not sure how and whether it is possible to get the std::cout ,from the programs the terminal is running, in the manner i wish.

i have read something about set stdhandle on windows, but im not sure how it works or whether it works in the way I wish, as the documentation for it is barebones; I haven't been able to talk to anyone familiar with it.

Comment: IIRC when you call `CreateProcess` to create a new process, you can pass a `STARTUP_INFO` and one of the things in `STARTUP_INFO` is where you want the stdout to go to. You can create a pipe and make stdout go to the pipe and then your console program can read from the pipe.

Comment: note that functions like `SetConsoleTextAttribute` will never ever be able to work in a custom console on Windows. That's just how Windows is designed - only the built-in Windows console is the *real* console.